# How to remove existing attribute from DTO

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

How can I remove existing attribute from DTO for example 'name' from ProductData. and is it possible? is the solution somewhere at my customextension-beans.xml ?

Comment: Any reason why you try to do this. there is no option to do this in the beans.xml files. can't you just leave the field blank/null in the populator?

Comment: It is a technical task.